# Regular polygon Interior angles

Tags: geometry, polygons

I am to find if any given angle(**say x**)can be interior angle of regular polygon.In other words,is there a regular polygon which angles are equal to **X**.

I know the formula for sum of interior angles of polygon i.e **(n-2)*180**.
I tried looping from sides 3 to 10000 and pushing back **((n-2)*180)/n** and after this pre-computation i tried searching each given angles.Please see code if not clear

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
 // your code goes here
  int t;
  cin>>t;
  vector<int>v;
  for(int i=3;i<=1000;i++)
   v.push_back(((180)*(i-2))/(i));
  while(t--)
   {
     int a;
     cin>>a;
     if(find(v.begin(),v.end(),a)!=v.end())
     puts("YES");
     else
     puts("NO");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This is giving correct answer for some values but not all.

**Is there any better(geometrical way) to do this ?**

**EDIT**:-

I have seen the solution and it was something like true if **(360%(180-x)==0)** else **false**.I still can't get it(why 360%(180-x).Anybody please explain this or give different way

Comment: `v.push_back(((180)*(i-2))/(i));` should be `v.push_back(((180)*(i-2))/double(i));`

Comment: Why double MR@AlexeyBurdin .Well even after type cating it is not giving correct answer.

Comment: So the problem is "Determine if there is a regular polygon with interior angle **strictly equal to** that given **integer** degrees"?

Comment: possibly i am not clear enough.You can see this sir,http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/270/A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A,B$ be the consecutive vertices of a regular $n$-vertices polygon and $O$ be it's center.
$\angle AOB=\frac{360^{\circ}}{n}$, $\Delta AOB$ is isosceles, so $\angle OAB = \frac{180^{\circ} - \angle AOB}{2}$ and the interior angle $=2\angle OAB = x^{\circ}$ and $x$ is integer.
We are to find whether it could be an integer $n$ that gives that $x$.
$$180-\frac{360}{n}=x$$
$$\frac{360}{n}=180-x$$
$$n=\frac{360}{180-x}$$
So `puts(360%(180-x)?"NO":"YES")` should work. :)

Comment: Wow....thanks a lot!!!!